# AMD Radeon HD 7640G inverting colours

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, graphics-card, colors, amd-radeon

I have not been able to find anyone else on the internet that has had this issue, so I am hoping someone will be able to help me out.

When you plug in or remove any external device, VGA/HDMI/USB the screen temporarily displays everything in inverted colours (see pictures). This behaviour also occurs when I try to close the Device Manager windows when there is an active properties dialog box that must be closed first.

This is just to show how the colour inverts, Device Manager is open with the Generic PnP Monitor properties dialog open: Desktop before closing Device Manager

I clicked on the close on the Device Manager window (notice how the close box is a different colour), and the colours invert like this: 
[image: Close Invert]

Immediately after clicking close the screen inverts colours:
[image: Close Invert]

As soon as I move the mouse, or after about half a second, the colour returns to normal. Sometimes the colour only returns to normal after I hover the mouse over that portion of the screen, but I couldn't replicate for screenshots. Moving mouse refreshes screen and reverts colour back to normal.

It is not an internal display cable issue with my monitor or VGA/HDMI cable for second screen, as I can screenshot the issue. Which lead me to think that the problem was likely a driver problem. So I went to roll back the display driver, but it was still on the initial version and there was no update for it - I checked! So I uninstalled the AMD Radeon Display Driver, and rebooted to safe mode (so I am sure it's not some other app messing with the graphics). I still have the same issue, unplugging my USB mouse receiver inverts the colour, and the same happens when I plug it back in.

I have downloaded the AMD Auto Detect and Install Driver tool, which has installed the same Display Driver that came with my laptop. But I still have this issue.

Any help would be appreciated, here's some relevant system info:

System Specs: Toshiba Satellite L855D AMD A8-4500M APU Integrated Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 7640G Windows 8.1

Comment: if the inverted colors only stay that way until you do something, what is the problem?  OR in your good description of the problem here is there something I am missing?

Comment: The problem is that the colours are inverting at all. Sure it's not exactly performance crippling and it doesn't have any other affect on the computer that I can see, but it's slightly annoying to have the colors invert and freeze up when I plug in devices. I've never seen this on any PC before as either a feature or otherwise, so I was wondering if there was some other fix I might be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK for anyone else who may have this problem, I have found a temporary solution:
Set up another Windows User Account, I set up a local one, should fix the problem when you are logged in with the new account. I am guessing there is a problem with some application I have installed that is causing the display card to play up. Never heard of this but the second account has solved the problem.

Edit - Feb 2015:

After upgrading to Windows 10 I still had the issue, I should have guessed that it was a setting that was causing the flashing not a driver bug. But because Windows synced my personal settings from the cloud when I set up Windows 10 I realized that was why creating a local account would "fix" the issue. So I eventually stumbled across the culprit in the Settings app: I had enabled an Accessibility Option that flashes the entire screen inverted instead of playing a notification sound. No idea how this got enabled in the first place but it was a relief to find the solution.

So the actual solution is to disable this setting, in Windows 10, is open Settings > Ease of Access > Other options > Visual Notification > and set "Flash active title bar", instead of "Flash entire display". That's it!

Comment: I cannot mark the updated answer as the solution for two days...but the edited answer is has solved this issue.

Comment: If a new user profile solves it, it could be there was some software that ran under the older profile that has that "feature" of inverting colors? And that feature kicked in at the wrong times, and when not specifically told to.